# Packaging Document Structures and templates in Liferay plugin wars

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-6

Is there a way to include Liferay document or web-content structures and templates in portlet plugin war files and have them become available to users like the standard ones are?

The use-case would be that you are writing a portlet that takes advantage of a custom Document Library structure that you are providing.  But you don't want to distribute this structure as a separate thing with its own installation procedure (such as providing a LAR just for the structure), you just want your plugin to make the custom structure available whenever it is installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your goal by adding a **portal.properties** file to the **WEB-INF/classes** directory of your portlet. This file should contain the following line:

```
application.startup.events=com.yourcompany.whatever.YourCustomStartupAction
```

This custom startup action should be a class that extends from **com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.SimpleAction**. In it you will be able to leverage all the Liferay service utils to do things in Liferay at the moment your portlet is started. The class you need to use to work with the Liferay document library specifically is [DLAppLocalServiceUtil](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/service/DLAppLocalServiceUtil.html). This util class has all the necessary methods to work with files/folders in the document library.

For web content related stuff, such as structures, templates and articles, just use [JournalStructureLocalServiceUtil](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/journal/service/JournalStructureLocalServiceUtil.html), [JournalTemplateLocalServiceUtil](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/journal/service/JournalTemplateLocalServiceUtil.html) and [JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/journal/service/JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.html).

Comment: So I think you are suggesting that I should create a startup action that uses the service layer to create and store my structure's XML directly into the JournalStructure table.  This seems worth a try, for  Web Content structures.

Comment: So I think you are suggesting that I should create a startup action that uses the service layer to create and store my structure's XSD directly into the JournalStructure table.  This seems worth a try, at least for  Web Content structures.

For custom document library metadata, I guess the analog would be DDMStructureLocalService and DDMTemplateLocalService.

Comment: It's a universal approach to do anything with Liferay during the startup of a WAR, the portlet in this case (usually we use a hook and let the portlet depend on that to be deployed). The only thing you have to take into account is the result of the hook being deployed and redeployed, etc... . This means you have to introduce code that does some checks, e.g. if the structure exist then update is, overwrite it with the version in the portlet, whatever you want really... .

Answer (score 1):

I hope i got your question right ;)
You could create the folder Structure via the DLFolderService when the portlet is deployed.
To run a method when the Server starts you will have to use the CustomAction i think, check it out : [here](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/performing-a-custom-acti-4)